# getAt(<key>) returns null but get(<key>) returns the desired object

Tags: groovy, hashmap

I am using groovy, and I ran into a problem today where calling getAt("key") returned null but calling get("key") returned the desired object.

the method call in question is part of a much larger script where in I use getAt() every where else. there is only one particular instance in which I have to use get("key") instead of getAt("key")

Sorry but I can't paste code here.

I am just looking for an explination as to why get and getAt would produce different results when referencing a key (not an index)

As far as I am away they should work the same in regards to hash maps in groovy

```
theMap = ["A": [:],
           "B": [:],
           "C": [:],
           "D": [:],
           "E": [:],
           "F": [:],
           "G": [:],
           "H": [:],
           "I": [:],
           "J": [:]]
```

later on in the code I have this....

```
if (theMap.getAt("J").keySet().contains(iterationVariable)) {
    theMap.getAt("J").getAt(iterationVariable).add("someStuff")
} else {
    theMap.getAt("J").put(iterationVariable, ["someStuff"])
}
```

So the null pointer exception occurs at

```
theMap.getAt("J").getAt(iterationVariable).add("somestuff")
```

after a second iteration at which point J already looks like this
    "J": ["someKey": ["some other stuff"]]

if I change getAt to get it works fine.

Comment: Is your key a string?

Comment: Can you come up with an example that shows what you mean? It's hard to debug anecdotes

Comment: Yeah Let me see if I can write something up It will be a few mins though

Comment: add the code to a gist we can edit it inti your question @switch201

Comment: ok I added some code, but I am sorry if it doesn't help much. The thing is... by my accounts I don't see anything wrong... get and getAt should be interchangeable as i understand it. And as I said before I use getAt every where else....

Comment: Any chance of an example that runs?

Comment: Why `keySet().contains(iterationVariable)` when `containsKey(iterationVariable)` exists? --- Why check if it contains an Apple (`iterationVariable`) then try to get an Orange (`"someKey"`)?

Comment: didn't know aboutt containsKey method... amd the other thing is that was a mistkae editing now

Comment: ok I fixed my mistake there hope it makes more sense

Comment: But more importantly, why are you calling `getAt()` in the first place? The [GroovyDoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#getAt(java.lang.Object)) says: *Support the subscript operator for a Map.* The method is not intended for direct use, it's there so you can write `map["someKey"]` instead of `map.get("someKey")`. I suggest you get rid of the `getAt()` calls.

Comment: @Andreas yeah thats the plan for right now. I asked this question because I just don't understand why they would produce different results. like others are saying getAt() simply calls get() in its method decleration so it should work the same, but in this case it does not :/

Comment: @switch201 just out of curiosity, how *exactly* are you calling `get()`? By exactly I mean the actual line of code.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using GroovyConsole 2.4.3 with Java 1.8.0_91. Took your code as shown, added `iterationVariable = "test"`, and it ran fine, updating `theMap` to this: `[A:[:], B:[:], C:[:], D:[:], E:[:], F:[:], G:[:], H:[:], I:[:], J:[test:[someStuff]]]`. --- Simplified entire if construct to `theMap["J"].get(iterationVariable, []) << "someStuff"` and it still ran fine.

Comment: @Johny Henly instead of "theMap.getAt("J").getAt(iterationVariable).add("someStuff")"

I do 
"theMap.getAt("J").get(iterationVariable).add("someStuff")"

Comment: Thanks for the help ya'll sorry that this is shitty question... if it helps, it seems the issue only occurs with the "J" map while other maps appear to work fine.

sorry I can't paste the real code for you guys, if I could I would. I guess it just might always be a mistory

Answer (score 0):

They do return the same result at least in some circumstances, run this in the Groovy console and you'll see that both assertions pass

```
def m = [a: 2]

assert m.getAt('a') == 2
assert m.get('a') == 2
```

As for why they don't return the same result in *your* case, who knows, you haven't told us anything about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object in question is a `Map`, so that the `get("key")` method you're referring to is the [`Map.get(Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) method, then the Groovy `getAt("key")` method will do the exact same thing, because it's implemented like this in class `DefaultGroovyMethods`:

```
public static <K,V> V getAt(Map<K,V> self, K key) {
    return self.get(key);
}
```

As you can see, `getAt()` simply calls `get()` when context object is a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer your question, but you can do:

```
theMap = ["A": [:],
           "B": [:],
           "C": [:],
           "D": [:],
           "E": [:],
           "F": [:],
           "G": [:],
           "H": [:],
           "I": [:],,
           "J": [:]]

letter = 'J'
key = 'someKey'
stuff = 'someStuff'

theMap[letter].get(key, []) << stuff

assert theMap.J == [someKey:['someStuff']]
```

To do the same thing

Comment: yeah I mean technically I already found the solution which is to use get instead of getAt in this case. I asked this question because as far as I can tell getAt should work. (I mean I use it alot) so I was just hoping to get some insight on why they may behave differently. but thanks for the response

Comment: Yeah it was more a comment on how you can simplify your code

Comment: `theMap."$letter"."$key"` is a rather slow/weird way to write `theMap[letter][key]`. I would also suggest doing `theMap[letter].get(key, []) << stuff`, as exemplified in the GroovyDoc for [`get(Object key, Object defaultValue)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Good call Andreas (yoink) ;-)